# How to register a Observer using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, observer-pattern

I want to implement the GoF Observer Design Pattern using Spring Boot without Spring Events.
 Code sample:

```
    @Component
    public class MyObservable extends java.util.Observable {
      void myObservableMethod(Object obj){
        notifyObservers(obj);
      }
    }

    @Component
    public class MyObserver implements java.util.Observer{  
    @Override
      public void update(java.util.Observable observable, Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
      }
    }
```

1. Are the java.util classes a good implementation for that pattern ?
2. How can I register the observer with the observable , and still able to use Spring Depedency Injection?
   Where I can call myObserver.accept(myObservable); ?

   ```
   @Autowired
   MyObservable myObservable;
   @Autowired
   MyObserver myObservable;

   myObserver.accept(myObservable); //??
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the java.util classes a good implementation for that pattern ?

The GoF pattern and the java implementation of it are a bit dated and have some issues.
It really depends on the problem you are trying to solve, but it might be suitable if your application doesn’t make massive use of events and you don’t want to introduce something like spring events or RxJava.

> How can I register the observer with the observable , and still able
>   to use Spring Depedency Injection? Where I can call
>   myObserver.accept(myObservable); ?

See the below example of how you can define an Observable some observers, wire them up and finally send some events to them.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ObserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ObserverApplication.class, args)){
            Observable observable = ctx.getBean(Observable.class);
            observable.notifyObservers("Hello");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Observable myObservable(){
        return new MyObservable();
    }

    @Bean
    MyObserver observer1(){
        return new MyObserver(1);
    }

    @Bean
    MyObserver observer2(){
        return new MyObserver(2);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureObservers(Observable myObservable, MyObserver observer1, MyObserver observer2){
        myObservable.addObserver(observer1);
        myObservable.addObserver(observer2);
    }

    static class MyObserver implements Observer {

        int id;

        public MyObserver(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            System.out.println("Observer: " + id + ", Received object: " + arg);
        }
    }

    static class MyObservable extends Observable {
        @Override
        public void notifyObservers(Object arg){
            this.setChanged();
            super.notifyObservers(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But where configureObservers() is called ?
And there are better ways to implement this ?

Comment: If a method is annotated with `@Autowired` and the class it belongs to is a bean, then spring will try and wire the method during context initialization, it will try and find beans matching the arguments and call the method. I have given you the best answer I can on how to use java.util to implement the Observer pattern, if you want advice on using spring events, or some other framework, then you probably need to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Magnus!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, the observer is not called by the observable in my program.
I suppose that spring construct a pool of objects and configureObservers() config just one instance of injected Observeble. Is there a want to set all objects of  this poll ?

Comment: Beans in spring are generally singletons, if you manually create the object then it will be a different instance. The my example there is one observable and two observers, but there is no reason you couldn’t adapt it for any fixed number of observables/observers. If you don’t know how many there will be, ie you need to generate the objects dynamically at runtime, then it becomes trickier, and its probably best to just leave spring out of the lifecycle.